# Generated sql case

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I'm trying to convert some old data with new data from the new table.

I created a sql script that returns the build up for a case statement.
This is an example what i get from the select statement: 'WHEN a = 2 THEN 350'.

```
UPDATE A
SET A.a = CASE
        (SELECT CONCAT('WHEN a= ', PP.Id, ' THEN ', LI.Id)
            FROM  A PP
                JOIN B LI ON LI.Description = PP.Name
                    JOIN C L ON LI.List_Id = L.Id
        WHERE L.Code = 'Code')
    END
```

So normally it should generate for each code this line:

CASE WHEN a = 1 THEN 2

CASE WHEN a = 2 THEN 3

CASE WHEN a = 3 THEN 4

...

But when I want to execute the code it gives a error on the END statement. This is probably because it expect it to be like CASE WHEN a = 1 THEN 0 END and not a select statement.

Is there a workaround or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Huh?  What do you want the data to look like?

Comment: We had for each section one table with the different possibilities for a dropdown. And now we created ONE table with all the items for all sections. But now they have different id's so i am converting the old id's to the new ones. And because that section has 60 different options I should write 60 case statements to convert it to the new id's. So that is why I created a select statement that automatically creates the WHEN Statement so i don't have to do that 60 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to build a `case` expression (that will not work the way you are attempting), you could use a subquery to select the value of `li.id` where `A.a = pp.id` like so:

```
UPDATE A
  set A.a = (
  select li.id 
  from A PP
    JOIN B LI ON LI.Description = PP.Name
    JOIN C L  ON LI.List_Id = L.Id
  where pp.id = A.a
    and l.code = 'Code'
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `case` statement on each line in the table, then you can do:

```
UPDATE A JOIN
       LI
       ON LI.Description = PP.Name
    SET A.a = REPACE(REPLCE('CONCAT 'CASE WHEN a = [a] THEN [b] END',
                            '[a]', a.id), [b], li.list_id);
```

I don't see how this is actually useful, though.

If you just want the new value, then:

```
UPDATE A JOIN
       LI
       ON LI.Description = PP.Name
    SET A.a = li.list_id;
```